# Android studio switching between method variables and importing method variables

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I'm trying to import my app from eclipse to Android Studio. 
And I can't fix the issue:

In eclipse, if I'm trying to auto-complete some method I can import also variables name

like:
[image]

Before auto-complete:

[image]

After auto-complete:

And also I can switch between variables using "TAB" key. 
In android studio, if I auto-complete some method, I have only brackets "()" without variable names.

How do I add this feature to Android Studio and how do I add switching between word?
Update:After some research, I found this eclipse feature name - "Content assist -> Fill method arguments"

So, nobody have used this feature in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> inside the braces of methods to get to know all about the parameters to be passed in to the methods. Inserting a comma after any parameter will switch you to the next one and so on.

Comment: Ctrl+P pop up me print window.
\

Comment: make sure your pointer is inside the braces of method, what Ctrl + P is showing you to print because it is not possible .